# Sequence number from table as foreign key for other table. insert data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to insert data base on other table which contain unique sequence number. I would like to use it as a foreign key for other table. Explanation below. Hope guys you give me some suggestion because I'm confused and have no idea how to handle with that. So...

I have 2 tables which I would like to fill correctly using sequence number. Example which I hope briefly explain what I want to do:

I have sequence which name eg. **sequenceid**

I have **sampleid** table filled eg.

```
Column1
234234
53451
54576
```

Now I would like to insert into Table1 and Table2 some data which partly base on sampleid table and use sequence

```
Table1 

COLUMN1        COLUMN2     COLUMN3
sequenceid   'Somedata'    234234   -> from sampleid table
sequenceid   'Somedata2'   53451    -> from sampleid table
sequenceid   'Somedata3'   54576    -> from sampleid table




Table2 

COLUMN1                                COLUMN2    COLUMN3          COLUMN4
ID from table1.column1 as Foreign Key sequenceid 'Something else'   234234
ID from table1.column1 as Foreign Key sequenceid 'Something else'   53451
ID from table1.column1 as Foreign Key sequenceid 'Something else'   54576
```

Column 4 as you can see also contain data from sampleid table.

So for example table1 and table2 could looks:

```
Table1
   COLUMN1 COLUMN2  COLUMN3
    234    'text'    234234
    456    'text'    53451
    125    'text'    54576

Table2
    COLUMN1   COLUMN2 COLUMN3           COLUMN4  
    234         567   'Something else'   234234
    456         345   'Something else'   53451
    125         534   'Something else'   54576
```

As you can see, First column in Table2 contain sequenceId from Table1, Column2 contain other sequence number (not related) and Column4 contain Data from sampleid table.

Now, I don't know how to handle with that, should I use cursor?  But how I could refer to sequence number from Table1?
Maybe I should load that sequence number from Table1 into some other temporary table? 
Any sugestion? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to insert data into both tables at the same time, or do you already have the data in table1 and you're trying to populate table2 later with related data? If so where is the relationship and the other data coming from? And why do you have two tables - it looks like a 1-to-1 relationship from your sample, with duplicated data?

Comment: If I insert data into both tables at the same time then I will get random sequence id in both.You asked about other data - that only an example. I have 2 tables, I need to fill them base on sampleid table. Data from sampleid table should be insert into table1.column3 and table2.column4. That's of course is easy to do. Next step is to create insert random number(sequence) into table1.column1 and somehow use the SAME  sequence from table1.column1 to table2.column1

Comment: OK, but are you inserting a row into table1 then a row into table2, then another row into table1 and one into table2; or are you putting lots of rows into table1 in one go, then lots of rows into table2?

Comment: If I will just insert at the same time data into 2 tables for example, insert into table1(sequence.neextval,'sdsd',number from sampleid (need to use cursor), and insert into table2 (sequence.nextvalue,'sdd' (...), In result I will get two different numbers.

Comment: No, I have to put a lot of rows into table1 in one go

Comment: Maybe there is some better way to approach that issue. I just have to fill that 2 tables, no matter how

Comment: After all, If I would like to select data from tables then I would like to use statement: Selecct * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.column1=t2.column2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell quite what you mean, but if you're inserting pairs of rows into the two tables together then you the normal approach would be to utilise the sequence behaviour with [the `nextval` and `currval` pseudocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253):

```
insert into table1 (column1, column2, column3)
values (sequenceid.nextval, 'text', 234234);
insert into table2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
values (sequenceid.currval, null, 'Something else', 234234);
```

Notice that the first insert uses `nextval`, the second one uses `currval` - as long as you're in the same session, that will reuse the last value obtained via `nextval`.

But in your case you want to use the same sequence to set another column in the second table; this doesn't work:

```
insert into table2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
values (sequenceid.currval, sequenceid.nextval, 'Something else', 234234);
```

It looks like it should, but within a statement the reference to `currval` will use that's statement's `nextval`, so you'd get the same value inserted into both columns. Or you would if that didn't violate the foreign key constraint.

I can see two approaches. The first is to use the first version, initially setting `table2.column2` to null and then updating it, which could potentially be done after all of the inserts have been completed:

```
update table2 set column2 = sequenceid.nextval where column2 is null;
```

That's won't work if `column2` is not nullable though.

The second approach is to use PL/SQL to keep the generated value, which may work for you if you're really using cursor loops already:

```
declare
  l_seq_value number;
begin
  l_seq_value := sequenceid.nextval;
  insert into table1 (column1, column2, column3)
  values (l_seq_value, 'text', 54576);
  insert into table2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
  values (l_seq_value, sequenceid.nextval, 'Something else', 54576);
end;
/
```

If you're looping in a PL/SQL block anyway you can just put that inside the loop.

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/382a4/1) of both approaches.

Comment: Oh my god, I forgot about possibility to use curval of sequence... I will try your solution tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot Alex for help : )

Comment: Alex, I'm trying to insert data into insert into table values (sequence1.nextval,sequence1.currval,sequence1.nextval) , but Output is for example (5,5,5,). Is there some way how to do for example (5,5,6) ?

Comment: @maciek2791 - that's exactly what I said would not work. You have to set the column values in separate statements (insert, then update); or track with a variable. I've shown both methods.

Comment: Yeah, It seems to work fine, You were right :) Thanks again Alex :)